# (SWIFT 4) How to calculate sum of the columns indexpath.row in the tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, indexpath

how to calculate the sum of the same columns in different cells, not the sum in the same cell.

I don't know how to solve it.

```
import UIKit

class ResultViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBAction func backPage(_ sender: Any) {
        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    let ad2 = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    @IBAction func resetHist(_ sender: Any) {
        ad2?.listPrice = [String]()
        ad2?.listAmt = [String]()

        tableview.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return ad2?.listPrice.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        cell.resultPrice?.text = ad2?.listPrice[indexPath.row]
        cell.resultAmt?.text = ad2?.listAmt[indexPath.row]

        var sum = 0

        // how to calculate sum of the same columns in different cells
        for i in ad2?.listPrice.count {

            sum += Int(ad2?.listPrice[i])

        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example? Not quite understanding what column means here. (Not sure you understand what column means either, no offense)

Comment: Sorry. I am immature in English.
column means Each element of tableviewcell
ex) listPrice[0], listPrice[1], ...

Comment: What you are going to use it for in `cellForRowAt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to enumerate over elements the way you try to do:

```
var sum = 0
for pair in listPrice.enumerated() {
    sum += Int(pair.element) //listPrice[pair.index]
}
```

Or just use this:

```
let sum = ad2?.listPrice.compactMap(Int.init).reduce(0, +)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `compactMap` to map the `String` array to `Int` and `reduce` to sum up the items.

```
let ad2 = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

...

let sum = ad2.listPrice.compactMap(Int.init).reduce(0, +)
```

and `cellForRow` is the wrong place for the code.

Notes :

- Basically don't use multiple arrays as data source.
- If `listPrice` contains numeric values anyway use a more appropriate type like `Int` or `Double`.
- Don't use `AppDelegate` as a common place to store data.
- If `AppDelegate` doesn't exist the app won't even launch so it's perfectly safe to force cast it.